# Redis standalone server is changing configuration on the fly

Tags: redis, configuration, redis-cli

I'm running a Redis instance as standalone server with the config as follow:

```
#bind option is commented
protected-mode no
port 6379
timeout 0
supervised no
```

The problem is the instance is running normally but passed some time it just hung out and don't let establish any incoming connection rather than localhost. When I check the logs I see this:

```
* SLAVE OF 45.148.122.184:39844 enabled (user request from 'id=214 addr=45.148.122.184:32324 fd=30 name= age=0 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=slaveof')
* Connecting to MASTER 45.148.122.184:39844
# Unable to connect to MASTER: Permission denied
* Connecting to MASTER 45.148.122.184:39844
# Unable to connect to MASTER: Permission denied
* Connecting to MASTER 45.148.122.184:39844
# Unable to connect to MASTER: Permission denied
```

In the config I'm not setting any slave or master server. even this cluster option is disabled. I don't recognize the IP address either.

Every time I restart the service it runs well and after a few hours the same happens. the sentinel service is disabled and not running.

What can I do to solve this?
Is this a configuration issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your Redis host has external IP and accessible to everyone on the internet and someone spotted it and uses [slaveof](https://redis.io/commands/slaveof) has to spoil your server accidentally or intentionally.

I recommend you at least [set up authentication](https://redis.io/topics/security) or/and restrict access to your Redis host with a firewall.

Comment: Done! Thanks a lot. I renamed some suggested commands and configured the firewall to deny access from external servers.